# Develop for Win10 UWP using a library for WinPhone 8, Can I?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, uwp

The question is can I develop a UWP (universal windows platform) using a library that was written for windows phone 8? what about a library for windows phone 8.1?

thanks

Comment: Well you can try it. Create a new uwp app and try to add the libraries as a reference. See if you get any errors. 
In all probabilty the windows phone 8 library will not work because it is a silverlight library. Windows 10 uses winrt.  
The windows phone 8.1 library may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it, only if you dont use any of the windows phone 8 API's